# Check if strings in column start with any of the strings in an array?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column containing strings. For each row in the column, I want to check if the string starts with one of several strings contained in an array. This array can contain any number of strings to check against the column.

The output I want is an array {TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;*etc*} where it returns TRUE if the string begins with any of the strings contained in the array.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

**Edits for clarification:** Office 365 (version 2109). I can't share the spreadsheet itself, but the column contains values like {1.1;1.1.1;1.1.2;1.2;1.3;*etc*}, and the arrays in question are things like {1.1;1.2}, so I want it to know which cells in the column begin with 1.1 or 1.2 in that case. So it's basically a hierarchically ordered list and I want to be able to pull into an array whether a given row of data is either a child of or is itself any of the items in the array.

Ideally it would be a formula only solution but I'm cool with VBA if it's necessary.

Example data

[image]

Bear in mind that in the real data there are many cells in column B which include way more than just two entries.

Comment: What version of Excel is this for? Can you post a small example together with expected results?

Comment: Office 365 (version 2109). I can't share the spreadsheet itself, but the column contains values like {1.1;1.1.1;1.1.2;1.2;1.3*etc*}, and the arrays in question are things like {1.1;1.2}, so I want it to know which cells in the column begin with 1.1 or 1.2 in that case. So it's basically a hierarchically ordered list and I want to be able to pull into an array whether a given row of data is either a child of or is itself any of the items in the array.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include any clarifications.  Please include a mock up of the data, and expected output.  Also note if you want a formula or vba and tag it correctly with the desired methodology.

Comment: @ScottCraner gotcha, done

Comment: So from "the arrays in question are things like {1.1;1.2}", I infer that these arrays only ever contain numerics, and not entries such as "1.1.1", which would necessitate being entered as a string?

Comment: No, they contain strings, they can be 1.1.1 or whatever.

Comment: So your column contains mixed datatypes, i.e. where it can be interpreted as a decimal it has been, otherwise it's text? Or have you reformatted entries such as 1.3 as the number-stored-as-text '1.3?

Comment: In response to @ScottCraner I have included some example data showing the overall picture I'm working with, this probably gives you a sense of what I'm asking for too. I already have a VBA formula based on evaluate() which is converting each cell in column B into an array, the difficulty is just coming up with a formula to identify the "child" IDs. Obviously once I've done that I can just use FILTER to get column C.

Comment: In your example `1.1.2` does not exist in column A but is still returned in C5, why?  Is this an omission by accident or do we include it just because it is in the list in B5?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first entry to be checked is in `A1`:

`=0+LEFT(A1,LEN(MyArray))=MyArray`

placed somewhere within the worksheet, will produce a spill array of the same dimension as *MyArray* and comprising the required Booleans. I leave it to you to decide what to do with that resulting array.

Comment: Ah, this solution is back-to-front, I think? I don't want to check the array for whether there are any values in the column which start with it, I want to check the column for rows which start with any of the strings in the array, and output that as a (very long) array. This will be going inside a FILTER formula if that helps you get a sense of what I need.

Comment: Perhaps more the reason that you should include a small example output with your question?

Answer (score 0):

We can use MMULT and MATCH to return the correct array:

```
=LET(
    lkprng,   FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),
    depcll,   B2&CHAR(10),
    depclm,   FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(depcll,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),
    dep,      TRANSPOSE(depclm&""),
    mtch,     --(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(lkprng,LEN(dep)),dep,0))),
    mmt,      MMULT(mtch,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(dep))),
              TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(lkprng,mmt>0,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry, this won't work. The input array is actually an array, not just a list of cells (generated by a formula that will be nested inside this one). And also I need the output to be in an actual array as well, because this bit will itself be nested inside a FILTER: basically this amounts to a constraint that I need the input to be the entire 'A' column, in your example, not just A1.

Comment: If you would please mock up the start and what you want, we can help better, but trying to come in the middle and guess where you are going is hard.  We may find a better method than what you are trying to do.  ie, "I have this on my sheet, in the end I want this. I have started here."  But give us the full picture.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I'm new here, I don't know the drill. This is just the one part I can't solve of a very complicated problem heh. But basically this is about setting up dependency tracking on a spreadsheet containing a very long list of hierarchically organised requirements. The column I'm searching is the ID numbers of the requirements, and the input array contains the requirements on which they depend (i.e. the requirements which will have to be developed prior to developing this one)...

Comment: ...The problem is, some of the dependencies are stated at the parent level, so I have to be able to identify all of the child requirements of that dependency. I'll use FILTER to do that once I have identified all the requirements which are children of the stated dependencies, but it's specifically identifying the children which I can't do.

Comment: Again, you will need to edit your post to include a mock up in tabular form of the starting point.  And a mock up of the inputs we need to use.  And a mock up of the expected results.  All in tabular form.  Words just cannot convey the details that good mock up of the data and output can.

Comment: @DanHartas see edit